# How to combine Elasticsearch highlighting and query types?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, highlighting

If I do a search like:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "should" : [
          {"match" : { "FullName" : "MiddleName1" } },
          {"match_phrase" : { "FullName" : "FirstName2 LastName2" } }
      ]
    }    
  }
}
```

I would get documents like:

```
{
...
"_id": "1",
...
  "FullName" : "FirstName1 MiddleName1 LastName1",
...
}

{
...
"_id": "2"
...
  "FullName" : "FirstName2 LastName2",
...
}
```

I know highlighting shows what parts of the documents caused retrievals, but not what query type.
I can also do a multi query then merge the results.

Is there a way do a single query and find out what query type fields and tokens that caused certain documents to be retrieved?

Ideal result:

```
{
  "id" : "1",
  "clause" : "match",
  "field" : "FullName",
  "tokens" : ["MiddleName1"]
}

{
  "id" : "2",
  "clause" : "match_phrase",
  "field" : "FullName",
  "tokens" : ["FirstName2", "LastName2"]
}
```

Comment: wouldn't  setting [require_field_match option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#field-match) work

Comment: To my understanding that is for solving an issue similar to nested objects to array of inner objects, I went with named queries (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html)